# How to run the website on the second monitor

Tags: visual-studio, multiple-monitors

In a dual-monitor, in Visual Studio 2010, Can I run my windows application or web site on the second monitor ?

I mean when I run the application or website, it's open automatically on the second monitor.

If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

If you have your browser on the second monitor, when you run it if that's the default browser to run in, it'll open over there in a new tab.

Usually have my VS2010 on my left monitor, then FireFox on my right monitor. FireFox is also set to my default browser in VS2010, so all I need to do is press F5 or CTRL+F5 and it'll open in the right monitor.